# Heroku PG Dump Export and PSQL Import -> Double Encoding of Extended ASCII Characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku, encoding

I've inherited a Heroku Rails application, which I am attempting to migrate into my dev environment.

Heroku is running PG 9.1.9, Local is running PG 9.2.4. Rails 3.2.11, pg gem '0.13.2', Local OS Debian 7.

Heroku database info:

```
$psql -l "dbname=abc... user=aaa etc"
  Name |  Owner | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access 
 ---------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
abcdef | abcdef | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | abcdef=CTc/abcdef
```

AFAIK, the production PG database uses UTF8 encoding.

Exporting from Heroku:

```
pg_dump -C "dbname=abc... user=aaa etc" > dump_plain.sql
```

I used the **pg_dump -C** option to ensure that the database is re-created based off the dump file, to avoid encoding issues if I were to create the target database by hand.

The Heroku database

```
$head dump_plain.sql
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET escape_string_warning = off;
```

I then edit dump_plain.sql to change Database Name and Owner then import via:

```
psql < dump_plain.sql
```

No errors reported.

```
$psql -l
      Name       |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access 
 ----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
  imported_d     | only_me  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

PSQL reports that the encoding for both database is the same and Rail's database.yml, AFAIK, should be using the same encoding.

Rails database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: stm_test
  encoding: utf8
```

For some reason, extended ASCII characters such as ellipses (...), are doubly encoded when running the Rails3 webapp off the freshly imported database.

Screenshots to illustrate:

**Double Encoding on Local Dev**
[image: Double Encoding]

**Correct Encoding on Heroku**
[image: Shows Correctly on Production]

This data is stored as a TEXT column:

```
CREATE TABLE templates (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    screen_writer text, <---- stored here
    action_list text
);
```

psql select snippet on LOCAL

```
label: "\"\xE2\x80\xA6I was proud of having\xE2\x80\xA6\""
```

psql select snippet on Heroku (via heroku pg:psql > select ....)

```
label: "\"\xE2\x80\xA6I was proud of having\xE2\x80\xA6\""
```

Viewing a json snippet:

```
production: "label":"\"\u2026I was proud of having\u2026\""
local: "label":"\"\u00e2\u0080\u00a6I was proud of having\u00e2\u0080\u00a6\""
```

Note the additional \u00. Is the issue is related to the server's postgres client encoding settings?

LOCALE settings on Local dev match Heroku's:

```
$locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I feel I am missing a simple step and would be eternally grateful if anyone could nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure that web pages are different? I am wondering if your web server (I suppose you have two: one remote and one local) is putting the correct charset on the http response? If you save both pages, are them different on disk?

Comment: Hi @eppesuig. Thank you for the suggestion. Chrome's Network tab suggests that both web servers set encoding to utf-8 (Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8). I've updated the answer with a json sample from production and the local server after the restore.

Comment: Still, it doesn't seem an error on the dbms side. I am not a ruby expert, but are you also sure that the encoding should be "utf8"? I google a little bit and found "encoding: unicode" instead. Is that the same?

Comment: thank @eppesuig for giving me another avenue to investigate. It could indeed be a silly ruby issue! Thank you for coming back.

Comment: 99,9% this is a Ruby issue. Since the select from both databases returns exactly the same output, this fact means that there's something wrong while generating the JSON or HTML output from Ruby, so you should investigate the application.

Comment: So you found that it is not dbms related (that's because the SELECTs show identical result sets) but you have different html output both encoded in utf8. You still have a few options: 1) your application set a wrong encoding when connecting to dbms; 2) your application use a different escape sequence when connecting to dbms (hint: check "standard_conforming_strings" and the like for your dbms driver); 3) you application server uses some charset setting from its environment.
Just to be sure: what happen when you connect your local application to the production dbms directly?

Comment: @eppesuig spot on with 3). Local app has the same problem connecting to the production server. Looks like local Ruby issue. Super thank you for helping me narrow this down to Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

add to Rails.root/config/boot.rb

```
require 'yaml'
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck'
```